# Translation of a moniker in Wuxia fiction

Tags: translation

I'm reading/translating a novel that is not in English and encountered this moniker for one of the characters: 隱匕花. I'm having trouble coming up with a name that is both poetic and also keeps the original meaning. The woman that this moniker describes is beautiful, intelligent, and very competent in her martial arts. I think that the moniker is trying to hint that she is a beauty with a hidden lethality.

Comment: Try "Femme Fatale" (Fatal Woman),  French terms in the English language carry certain mystic

Comment: Thank you! However that moniker carries a connotation that I wouldn't quite associate with the character. She is extremely nice and gentle while Femme Fatale feels like a beautiful woman who know she is dangerous and will give an air of authority or power. The character in question is very delicate.

Comment: I found a translation called Dagger Hidden Flower on Google. Personally I prefer to use the name of a toxic flower in the real world. Two examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerium and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brugmansia

Comment: How about Stiletto Sue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

隱 - hidden

匕 - dagger

花 - flower

隱匕花 means "dagger hidden in flower"

It seems to be inspired by a famous Chinese moniker 棉裏針 (needle in cotton)
It describes someone who appears unaggressive and soft, but he could hurt you badly if you try to press him with force, so it is best to not lay a hand on him.

With the same logic, 隱匕花 would mean the same as a Chinese moniker "花中劍" meaning "sword in flower" or "dagger in flower" -- You can admire her beauty, but it is a bad idea to grab her with force